# How to run a command when the eclipse plugin is clicked?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, cmd, eclipse-plugin

I have a Plug-in Project in my Eclipse workspace. When I right click the project and click on 'Run as Eclipse Application', another Eclipse instance is opened and the plug-in is installed successfully. When the plug-in button is clicked, the application opens.

However, when I export the project, create the jar and place the jar under plugins folder, I'm able to see the plugin button, but when I click it, the application is not opening.

Below, I show the java class that is being executed:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("com.example.eclipse.plugin");
        URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("webspy/lib/abc.jar"), null);
        File file=null;
        try {
            url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
            file = URIUtil.toFile(URIUtil.toURI(url));

            String[] str={"java", "-jar", file.getAbsolutePath()};
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(str);
            Process p = pb.start();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The *plugin.xml* file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
      <actionSet
            label="Sample Action Set"
            visible="true"
            id="com.example.eclipse.plugin.actionSet">
         <menu
               label="FEAT"
               id="sampleMenu">
            <separator
                  name="StartWebSpy">
            </separator>
         </menu>
         <action
               label="&amp;Start WebSpy"
               icon="icons/sample.gif"
               class="com.example.eclipse.plugin.actions.SampleAction"
               tooltip="Start WebSpy"
               menubarPath="sampleMenu/sampleGroup"
               toolbarPath="sampleGroup"
               id="com.example.eclipse.plugin.actions.SampleAction">
         </action>
      </actionSet>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

It has to run an executable jar once the button is clicked. This is not happening when the plugin jar is placed in plugins folder. Please help what am I missing.

Comment: Check the .log file for errors. Run Eclipse with the -consoleLog option so that you will actually see those 'printStackTrace' messages. Add some logging or even just simple System.out.println messages to see how far your code is getting.

Comment: Hi Greg, i added logs and launched the eclipse with -consoleLog option. I didn't see any errors.Added syso after pb.start() whatever i added in syso its printing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your JAR file `webspy/lib/abc.jar` is not being included in your exported plug-in `com.example.eclipse.plugin`. For this reason, when you click the button, the application is not opened (because the JAR file cannot be found). Check the Error Log (Window -> Show View -> Error Log) and you will see an `Unhandled event loop exception`.

To solve this issue, you must explicitly state that the `abc.jar` file is included in your exported plug-in. This can be done in the **build.properties** file (in particular, in the **Binary Build** section) by checking the checkbox of the `abc.jar` file.

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for the reply i have included my jar in build.properties but no luck.

Comment: How strange, because your code works for me. Just two remarks. First, your exported plug-in should be located in the "dropins" folder, not the "plugins" folder. Second, and VERY IMPORTANT, make sure that you are creating the JAR file (abc.jar) properly. It must be a "Runnable JAR File". Have a look at this video to see how it is done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mE3rbtKm-pk. Try again, and if this works I will update my answer so you can, if you want, vote it up and accept it.

Comment: Hi Mario, i put it into dropins folder and started my eclipse but still no luck and no errors in log file. I have created a runnable jar file as per the video.

Comment: Your code works for me in both the Eclipse second instance and when I install the exported plug-in, so long as the abc.jar is runnable. What is the content of your abc.jar file? Are you 100% sure that it is not being executed? Try coding something trivial in your abc.jar, such as: "JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo"); frame.setVisible(true);" ... just to see if this code is actually being executed. Also make sure you are not getting any errors. Change the code of your "catch" statement, add "prints" to see what is happening ... you have plenty of choices to study what is going on.

Comment: In addition to what I just posted (5 min ago) in my previous comment, make sure that the abc.jar file is being included in your exported plug-in. You can do this by simply opening the  "com.example.eclipse.plugin.jar" file that you obtain. You can open this file using any application that opens compressed files, for example WinRar.

Comment: My jar file is an javafx application. Its running when i ran from eclipse as Run as Eclipse Application.But when i export as jar with including all dependent jars and depolyed in dropins folder its not working. I have created a sample javafx application which it launches a window saying "Hello" it is also not working. I am using eclipse kepler.

Comment: I would suggest that you try to make a trivial example work: remove your software dependencies, code the simplest possible JAR file, etc. It is not even necessary that it is a JavaFX application (in the begining). When you get a simple example running, built your application incrementally from it. This way you will be able to detect where the problem is. It might be, for example, your software dependencies not being properly installed in your RCP. If you try a trivial example, this problem might dissapear. Who knows.